# XML based image gallery in ios development help needed

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, xcode4.2, image-gallery

I searched every where and tried to do learn from the Apple document, but  did not success. Actually I learned to fetch XML, learned to Load Image, but not in the combined form.
Please suggest me some example if it does exist.

Answer (score 1):

I came here by asking the same question, After some struggle I've found an interesting article by IBM:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-iosslideshow/

This should help you ( and me) to build the gallery.

If not just add it as a "Guide" on how to achieve that.

If I learn how to do it properly I'll let you know how.

Cheers,
Wolf

Comment: thanks @Wolf for great help, that will help in some way... :)

Comment: Just to add, I've tried the code myself, and could not make it work on xcode 4.3 =/

Comment: Actually, it does work. It turned out to be my XML that was being parsed blank, somehow the server denied it and always rendered it Blank. Cheers!